# Proof for De Bruijn–Erdős

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, determinant

Background information: there is an incidence structure. So the structure is a triple pair $(P,L,\in)$ where $P$ is a set (its elements are called points), $L$ is a set (its elements are called “lines”) and we write $p\in l$ if the point $p$ lies on the line $l$ (is incident to it) and $p\not\in l$ if the reverse holds. It is assumed that $P,L$ are finite

Here is the theorem: suppose that for any two distinct points $p, p^{\prime}$ there is a unique line $l$ such that $p \in l$ and $p^{\prime} \in l$, and that not all points are on the same line. Then there are at least as many lines as points.

It is aimed to prove the above theorem

Here is a definition: let $T:\mathbb{R}^{P}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{L}$, $S:\mathbb{R}^{L}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{P}$ be the maps $(Tf)(l)=\sum_{p\in l}f(p)$ and $(Sg)(p)=\sum_{l\in p}g(l)$

Solving the questions by several subquestions.

Already finished:

(a) Suppose that for some point $p$ there is only one line containing $p$. Show that this line contains all points.

(b) $T,S$ are linear

(c) Suppose that $P=\{p_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is finite. Show that the matrix of $ST$ in the “standard basis” of $\mathbb{R}^{P}$(the ith basis vector is the function which is 1 at $p_i$, zero elsewhere) is $J_n +diag(d_1 − 1,...,d_n − 1)$ where $J_n$ is the all-ones matrix and $d_i$
is the number of lines through $p_i$.

(d) Suppose that not all points are on the same line. Show that $det(ST) > 0$.

Final step:

(e) Prove the theorem.

Could you please help me to solve (e)? Thanks.